# PHP: Can anyone help me how to create a payment request using wysow repository?

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I'm trying to figure out how to include PostFinance (Swiss Bank) payment processor, but unfortunately it is a very unclear documentation here and I cannot figure out how to handle it. 
I found a repo  https://github.com/wysow/wysow-postfinance
so if there're some php experts out there, I would appreciate if you can give me an example code to include on my clean index.php file, based on this library.

I already installed composer and included the library, but cannot make a test payment.

Last code I tried is the example in README file:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';



    use PostFinance\Passphrase;
    use PostFinance\Ecommerce\EcommercePaymentRequest;
    use PostFinance\ShaComposer\AllParametersShaComposer;
    use PostFinance\FormGenerator\SimpleFormGenerator;

    $passphrase = new Passphrase('MySecretSig123');
    $shaComposer = new AllParametersShaComposer($passphrase);
    //$shaComposer->addParameterFilter(new ShaInParameterFilter); //optional

    $ecommercePaymentRequest = new EcommercePaymentRequest($shaComposer);

    // Optionally set PostFinance uri, defaults to TEST account
    //$ecommercePaymentRequest->setPostFinanceUri(EcommercePaymentRequest::PRODUCTION);

    // Set various params:
  $ecommercePaymentRequest->setPspid('mypspid');
    $ecommercePaymentRequest->setOrderid('123456');
    $ecommercePaymentRequest->setAmount(1500); // in cents
    $ecommercePaymentRequest->setCurrency('EUR');
    // ...

    $ecommercePaymentRequest->validate();

    $formGenerator = new SimpleFormGenerator;
    $html = $formGenerator->render($ecommercePaymentRequest);

  echo $html;
    // Or use your own generator. Or pass $ecommercePaymentRequest to a view


 ?>
```

But the result is showing that it doesn't send all information, like total amount and beneficiary.
[image]

How do I fix that?

Comment: What have you tried, show us code. Its not like, i have a project, please help.

Comment: I tried a lot of thing, but let me give you the last code I tried.

Comment: The Git repo [README.md](https://github.com/wysow/wysow-postfinance/blob/master/README.md) file includes code examples...

Comment: I tried those examples, but for instance the EcommercePaymentRequest,, gives me an error :

Fatal error: Class 'ShaInParameterFilter' not found,