# Create PostFinance payment request

Tags: php, concrete5

[PHP: Can anyone help me how to create a payment request using wysow repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394552/php-can-anyone-help-me-how-to-create-a-payment-request-using-wysow-repository)

I found this link, but there weren't any solutions. I am am using concrete5's Community Store and am trying to create a PostFinance payment package/addon. I have the following code in /packages/community_store_postfinance/src/CommunityStore/Payment/Methods/CommunityStorePostfinance/CommunityStorePostfinancePaymentMethod.php file (which is a copy of the example in [GitHub](https://github.com/wysow/wysow-postfinance)):

```
$passphrase = new Passphrase($shaInSecret);
$shaComposer = new AllParametersShaComposer($passphrase);

$ecommercePaymentRequest = new EcommercePaymentRequest($shaComposer);

// Set various params:
$ecommercePaymentRequest->setPspid($postfinancePsid);
$ecommercePaymentRequest->setOrderid($custmerOrder->getOrderId());
$ecommercePaymentRequest->setPostFinanceUri(EcommercePaymentRequest::TEST);

$ecommercePaymentRequest->setAmount((Int)$amount);
$ecommercePaymentRequest->setCurrency('CHF');
$ecommercePaymentRequest->setCustomername($customerName);
$ecommercePaymentRequest->setOwnerAddress($address);
$ecommercePaymentRequest->validate();

$formGenerator = new SimpleFormGenerator;
$paymentForm = $formGenerator->render($ecommercePaymentRequest);
// I then pass this to my redirect view
$this->set('paymentForm', $paymentForm);
```

I have debugged and the form is being created and looks correct, as is required by PostFinance and I get redirected the the PostFinance payment confirmation page, but none of the details have been passed to PostFinance. I am just wondering whether I missed something or if I should be adding something else in the request for the form to go through automatically? Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A value set by `$this->set()` will be lost, when redirecting. You would need to set it into the session. Or you do the form generating in the method where you want to redirect to (you could call the code from above in this method, but instead of a redirect you need to return the generated form).

But I think there are other problems: `$this->set()` is normally a method from a controller (page-, block- etc. controller). But you are using it in a class from the `src` folder.
Another problem seems to be the path: `packages/community_store/postfinance/src/CommunityStore/Payment/Methods`. Should this not be `packages/postfinance/src/CommunityStore/Payment/Methods` because the package name is `postfinance` and not `community_store`?

Comment: HI @1stthomas, thanks for your response, I am trying a different package from packagist with a similar form creator, which I also set and sent to my redirect view, and the the test payment went through with a successful response, but it's frustrating for me not being able to see the differences clearly, and find the solution for this form creator. I checked the file path, and edited my question I checked the [addons from the Community Store] (https://github.com/concrete5-community-store) and have followed the file structure in the packages, so I don't  think  the path is incorrect.

Comment: Now the package name looks better. From wysow-postfinance: (...) Generate a form; Submit it to PostFinance (client side); (...) I do not see code, where you submit the form to PostFinance.

Comment: Thanks @1stthomas, on a bit of a break now, but will have to re-look at this when I get back. Sorry I can't upvote your answer as don't have enough reputation., to say thanks for your answers.

Comment: yw, I upvoted your question. You can now upvote answers (up to 15 rep). You can also accept an answer as correct which will give you further badges and reputation ;).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else wanted to know my solution, it was a dumb error on my part as all I had to do was `return` or `echo $paymentForm;` This solved my problem and successfully sent the form to PostFinance.

Although now I have the problem of not being able to get the PostFinance backend generated signature to match, [PostFinance Signature not matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245938/postfinance-signature-not-matching)

Comment: Please create a new question ;)

Comment: :) thanks @1stthomas I created it but then managed to answer my own question while typing it out. I fell into the trap of quickly reading the instructions and missing a vital piece of information from PostFinance, as assumed that test and prod environments were treated differently, but the answer is response signatures won't match if the SHA-IN and SHA-OUT passphrases are the same, as PostFinance automatically changes the SHA-OUT for security reasons.